# Model level method to call in before_filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working in rails 2, I have a model level method, which i want to call in before_filter. How can i do this?
I tried this way, but its not working

```
before_filter :LmsUser.can_edit_update, :only => [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add a method to your controller and use that as the before filter.  For example:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :check_permissions,
                :only => [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  private
    def check_permissions
      unless LmsUser.can_edit_update
        # redirect_to, render, or raise
      end
    end
end
```

See the [filters section of the Action Controller Overview guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/action_controller_overview.html#filters) for more information.